# Assigning different-sized array literals to the same variable in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Given something like this:

```
struct Strings {
  string[] s;
}

Strings[] memory strings = new Strings[](2);
```

I'm trying:

```
strings[0].s = ["a","b"];
strings[1].s = ["a","b","c"];
```

Which is giving me:

> TypeError: Type string memory[2] memory is not implicitly convertible
> to expected type string memory[] memory

> TypeError: Type string memory[3] memory is not implicitly convertible
> to expected type string memory[] memory

What's the most elegant way to make this work? Should I initialize **s**?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a fixed-size array `["a","b"]` into a dynamic-size array `string[] s`.

For each of the properties `s`, you need to predetermine the length of the dynamic size array beforehand, and then assign the values one by one.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
  struct Strings {
    string[] s;
  }

  function foo() external pure {
    Strings[] memory strings = new Strings[](2);

    strings[0].s = new string[](2);
    strings[0].s[0] = "a";
    strings[0].s[1] = "b";

    strings[1].s = new string[](3);
    strings[1].s[0] = "a";
    strings[1].s[1] = "b";
    strings[1].s[1] = "c";
  }
}
```